# JTextPane printing without print dialog box showing

Tags: java, swing, printing

I want to print `JTextPane` directly to printer without showing print dialog box and printing progress on screen. For this purpose, I found a following method in javadoc:

```
textPane.print(headerFormat, footerFormat, boolean showPrintDialog, 
     PrintService service, PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes, boolean interactive);
```

I do not understand the parameter 4 and 5. What values for parameters should I pass there for `PrintService` and `PrintRequestAttributeSet`?

Please guide me how can I use this method.

Comment: Isn't this what the API is for? Have you looked at the [JTextComponent API section on this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print-java.text.MessageFormat-java.text.MessageFormat-boolean-javax.print.PrintService-javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet-boolean-) yet? It looks pretty clear what the parameters are for, no?

Answer (score 1):

As @Hovercraft [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024513/jtextpane-printing-without-print-dialog-box-showing#comment63490089_38024513), the relevant [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print-java.text.MessageFormat-java.text.MessageFormat-boolean-javax.print.PrintService-javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet-boolean-) is your friend. The parameters are these:

```
headerFormat - the text, in MessageFormat, to be used as the header, or null for no header
footerFormat - the text, in MessageFormat, to be used as the footer, or null for no footer
showPrintDialog - true to display a print dialog, false otherwise
service - initial PrintService, or null for the default
attributes - the job attributes to be applied to the print job, or null for none
interactive - whether to print in an interactive mode
```

You might start with something like this to get the default/none behavior:

```java
textPane.print(null, null, false, null, null, false);
```

Comment: i use this `textPane.print(null, null, false, null, null, false);` but still print dialog box is showing.

Comment: Try "printing from an application with no visible GUI."